# How big is the zombies download for Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare?

Tags: ps3, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare, cod-advanced-warfare-zombies

How much data does it takes to download zombies for Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare on PlayStation 3? I use my phones wireless hot-spot mode to access online.

Comment: @DavidToh, what makes you think the user was asking about Havok? They were asking about "zombies", and while Havok was the first DLC to include a zombies map, both other DLCs currently available **also** include a zombies map.

Comment: @Timelord64 in that case, simply find out the file size of the respective dlcs.

Answer (score 2):

Havok is reported to come in three separate downloads, for a total of approximately 15GB.

> 3 file sizes on PS4 at 5.43 GB, 5.42 GB, and 5.62 GB.

[Source](http://www.product-reviews.net/2015/02/26/cod-havoc-dlc-3-download-file-sizes-confuse/)

There seems to have been quite the problem with the 3 download files taking several hours on end to download. I do not have any first hand experience with this issue but I cannot say for sure.

[File download sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDDcF.jpg)

Although this is in the case of a PS4 I believe that the file sizes will not change between the consoles. So expect about 15GB worth of downloads.